# how to display latest updated data in drop down field php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

How to display the latest updated data in select option? when i use update query to update this field, this customer name field did updated in the database but not update on the page itself? any way to solve this?

```
<td width="20%">
Customer Name.
</td>
<td width="40%" >
<select onchange="loadaddress()" style="width:400px" id="custname" name="custname" >
<option disabled>----------------------FJ----------------------</option>';  
                    <?php   for($i=0; $i<=odbc_fetch_row($result); $i++){
                        $id = odbc_result($result, 1);
                        $name = odbc_result($result, 2);
                        echo '<option value="'.$id.' '.$name.'"><b>'. $id. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;". $name.'</b></option>';     
                    }  
                    echo '<option disabled>----------------------FJL----------------------</option>';
                                for($i=0; $i<=odbc_fetch_row($result2); $i++){
                        $id = odbc_result($result2, 1);
                        $name = odbc_result($result2, 2);
                        echo '<option value="'.$id.' '.$name.'"><b>'. $id. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;". $name.'</b></option>';
                    }
                    echo '<option disabled>----------------------FJW----------------------</option>';
                                for($i=0; $i<=odbc_fetch_row($result5); $i++){
                        $id = odbc_result($result5, 1);
                        $name = odbc_result($result5, 2);
                        echo '<option value="'.$id.' '.$name.'"><b>'. $id. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;". $name.'</b></option>';
                    }

                    ?>
                        </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use (depending on your framework), `ajax` or `pjax` calls. Without methods like `pjax/ajax` you cannot asynchronously make calls to your server to get new data.

If you're using a php framework, I'm sure there's already an intergrated function/method caller for it.

Otherwise, see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more information.

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks, like laravel, Yii2 etc etc. All of those provide sufficient support. It's also possible to use jquery plugins for ajax content management.

Comment: can i straight away call back the variable like $custname？

Comment: @Jazlyn From an ajax call you'll probably get a model or array of models, depending on your situation. Using a for or each loop you can simply echo the contents when desired.

Comment: do u know where should i put the echo $custname? i still cant get the latest data, it keep show the 1st row data only.